# Laptop screen turns yellow

Tags: windows-10, colors

I'm currently using MSI GE-72 2QF. After the latest windows 10 update my laptop screen turned yellowish (white appears yellow). I color calibrated it from the settings and it got. But every time i turn it on, it turns yellow and have to go to color calibrate to fix. It does not really matter if i calibrate or not, i just have to go to calibrate settings and then just cancel it. 
Note: MSI True Color has also stopped working since the update.

Comment: Is it picking up a color from a background image? Right-click the desktop and select *Personalize*. On the left, select *Colors*. If *Automatically pick an accent color from my background* is checked, deselect it and manually pick a color.

Answer (score 4):

To solve the issue go to Settings -> Display -> Night light
-Turn off Night Light 
-If this doesn't work go into Night Light settings underneath Night Light and then click the white segment of the bar.

This should solve your problem it did for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but only in the late afternoon and evening. Windows now has a night setting which changes the hues on the screen. You can disable it by right-clicking on the screen and selecting display, You should see the night settings option

Answer (score 0):

Also check for rogue settings in vendor software. I was having this issue and finally traced it down to Lenovo's Vantage software half-enabling an "Eye Care Mode" which forced the screen white point down to 2800 K.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the color temperature in "Eye Care Mode" of lenovo vantage in case of a lenovo laptop. It should help

Comment: The questions doesn't mention a Lenovo Laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Display settings->Advanced display settings->Display adapter :properties for display 1->color management ->add-> "yourcomputer.icm",and click ok

Answer (score 0):

Mine is Asus Vivobook. For me it worked after i disabled "ASUS Optimization" in "msconfig". Just type msconfig in start menu and go to services tab.